# Hover on a child QGraphicsItem makes parent item hovered as well

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsitem

I have three items on a QGraphicsScene, say "1", "2" and "3". "3" is a child of "2". setAcceptHoverEvents enabled on all of them.

The problem is when I hover item "3" item "2" becomes marked as well even if the mouse position located outside 2's bounding rect. How can I hover child item independently?

[image]

```
#include "GraphicsView.h"

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent>

class GraphicsRectItem: public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    GraphicsRectItem(qreal x, qreal y, qreal w, qreal h, const QString& label, 
                     QGraphicsItem* parent = nullptr)
        : QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, w, h, parent)
        , m_label(new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(label, this))
    {
        setBrush(Qt::white);
        setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
    }

protected:
    void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent* event)
    {
        setBrush(Qt::lightGray);
        QGraphicsItem::hoverEnterEvent(event);
    }

    void hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent* event)
    {
        setBrush(Qt::white);
        QGraphicsItem::hoverLeaveEvent(event);
    }

protected:
    QGraphicsSimpleTextItem* m_label;
};

GraphicsView::GraphicsView(QWidget* parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
    , m_scene(new QGraphicsScene(this))
    , m_rect1(new GraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 100, " 1"))
    , m_rect2(new GraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 100, " 2"))
    , m_rect3(new GraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 100, " 3", m_rect2))
{
    m_scene->addItem(m_rect1);
    m_scene->addItem(m_rect2);

    m_rect2->setPos(40, 40);
    m_rect3->setPos(40, 40);

    setScene(m_scene);
}

GraphicsView::~GraphicsView()
{}
```

Comment: Testing the code you will realize that the event is fired first in the father, and then the son, why do you want to pass a father to some items?

Comment: I'd like to have a behavior like widgets have. I do realize that the parent item accepts hover event first because event starts from the scene and makes it way up to the child item. Having parent-child relationship is handy and natural to move/rotate items simultaneously e.g.

Comment: Btw, mouse press event works as expected. I can block it (not to pass further) inside the child item and the parent item will not accept it.

Comment: @Sam Davydov, Interesting observation: QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsToShape seems like the solution to that, as "The item cannot draw or receive mouse, tablet, drag and drop or hover events outside its shape." Though, it doesn't help at all, cause it doesn't work as described in the documentation.